# How to browse Android source code at a particular version?

Tags: android, git, android-source

I know that android source code is kept here: https://android.googlesource.com/, but I can't see any way to browse an old version of the code.
How would I view, say, `dalvik/libcore/concurrent/src/main/java/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java` in Froyo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clicking on the `platform/dalvik` repository.  Then scroll down to either one of the tags, or else the `froyo-release` branch (under `Branches`).  Then just keep following the `tree` links until you get to the right directory.  Then click on the the file you're interested in.

E.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/froyo-release/libcore/concurrent/src/main/java/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java

Answer (score 0):

You can browse any version online on [AndroidxRef.com](http://androidxref.com) and following is your file that you are looking for -- http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/prebuilt/sdk/4/android.jar

Answer (score 0):

This week Google [unveiled](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/12/code-search-with-cross-references-for-aosp.html) their official [Code Search with Cross References for the Android Open Source Project](https://cs.android.com/).
To see Froyo's LinkedBlockingQueue source code you can navigate to [this page](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-2.2.3_r2:dalvik/libcore/concurrent/src/main/java/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java).