# Where to get the source to Dalvik?

Tags: android-source, dalvik

When I try to get the Dalvik source the link listed on the project page is not working:

http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/

This link is listed and is not working:

http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=tree

Related:

[How to browse Android source code at a particular version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504576/how-to-browse-android-source-code-at-a-particular-version)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669329/since-android-git-kernel-org-is-down-where-do-i-get-source-code-for-android

Comment: http://androidxref.com/ is awesome and has been very reliable for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/

[The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130901000000*/http://android.git.kernel.org/) is showing that http://android.git.kernel.org/ was redirecting to http://android.googlesource.com/ some time ago.

Comment: I'm fairly surprised to find latest Jelly Bean code therein.  And ya, C++.