# Anyone know where I can find sample hardware/hardware c file for android

Tags: android, c, kernel

I'm trying to really get to know the android source code. I've downloaded what I thought would be the code, but it seems to lack many files that I would have expected there.

I'm looking for the hardware/hardware.c (cpp) file, and the hardware/power.c files.
Does anyone know where I could find some samples of this.  Or perhaps where I could find a book on the topic.

Comment: This topic would be very well suited on XDA-developers.com do. I would suggest you to go through some of the forum posts there. I've seen quite a few "building your own Rom" or "building Android from scratch" posts there. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/

See also: [Where to get the source to Dalvik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929424/where-to-get-the-source-to-dalvik)

Comment: Thanks heaps.  This week just gets better and better.

Comment: the only reason I didn't mark this as answered is because though I have several hundred files I'm still not sure it's in there.  I did vote up.